# Debugging: device connected but no frames are available

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, android-debug

I'm creating a singleton class and in this class I have arraylist in which I'm adding object of class ModelClass based on some condition

I want to see if object was added and what is the current state of arraylist in which objects are adding, how can I do this using debugging, what I'm doing right now I'm placing breakpoint(image attached) and running in debug mode, for this I'm getting connected to target vm(image attached) but nothing happening, what should I do?

[image: I'm getting this when I'm running in debugging mode]

my breakpoints [image: are]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

There are 2 debug options (from left to right) in Android Studio.
The first one restarts the app. It's usefull, when you need to check some code that initializes your MainActivity before any user interactions.

2nd option is more common. If your app is already running, and you want to check something that requires interaction, use 2nd option.

So what you have to do, is to invoke your code that has breakpoints. Depending on if it's called during initialization (1st option) or after some interaction (choose 2nd option and tap the element, that invokes the code).

Comment: I tried both running into normal and debug mode and attached debugger same output as image attached in question

Comment: Could this mean that your code is not invoked at all?